# Is "Put together" a phrasal verb?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

> She put all the flowers together in one big bunch.

Is "put together" a phrasal verb in this sentence? Or is "together" an adverb?

Comment: A close call. Adverb for how she put them all in one. Phrasal would have her assembling the flowers for the sake of her arrangement.

Comment: @YosefBaskin How about in "He put the crib together"?

Comment: @Barmar That's a good one. Phrasal there.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's what I thought, I already put it in an answer.

Comment: This is difficult because 'put' is a verb with odd argumentation, needing more than a subject and direct object. But one doesn't think of there being a multi-word verb in 'She put the bowl on the table' or She put the bowl down / She put down the bowl' (compare 'He picked up the bowl'). Perhaps surprising, as 'put down' = 'deposit'. I'd say this is a grey area. CGEL probably thinks of 'down' as a preposition here, just to add to the debate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is CGEL "The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language"?

Comment: @darkhealer Yes, CGEL is the definitive grammar of English.

Comment: 'Definitive' in the 'considered by many but by no means all [to have the best analyses on all topics]' sense. With 'definitive', it's almost as if inerrancy is being claimed ... so no further grammatical analysis should be undertaken, no assumptions challenged.

Comment: Thank you all a lot.

Comment: One argument for single-lexeme status (though I believe the term 'phrasal verb' is best discarded as different authorities use it in conflicting ways; I use 'multi-word verb') is that  'put together' is synonymous with 'assemble', with a large degree of overlap. Another is that the German equivalent 'zusammensetzen' is unarguably a single word. Strong arguments, I'd say, though I wouldn't have the temerity to claim '_put together_ **is** a MWV.' It's one analysis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth German is to a certain extent an agglutinative language, so its word structures are irrelevant here. The fact that "put together" is synonymous with "assemble" (or "combine) says nothing of its syntactic status. There is no argument I know of that claims that expressions like "put together" are single lexemes at word level. That would simply make no sense.

Comment: @BillJ The lexeme is defined by Crystal (who introduced the word) as a unit of lexical meaning. He gave metaphorical 'ship of the desert' as one example. Most people accept open compounds as multi-word nouns (there's little fundamental difference between the variants particle board and particleboard, for instance).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Crystal is not a grammarian. A quick glance at his Rediscover Grammar reveals that. How do you know that "most people accept open compounds as multi-word nouns"? "Particle board" is a syntactic construction consisting of  modifier+head, also "brick wall" and the like.

Comment: I'd suggest that a better definition of "lexeme" is 'a unit correponding to a word seen abstractly enough to include all of its **inflectional'** forms. For example,  _take, takes, taken_ and _taking_ are all forms of the lexeme _take_. Incidentally, my research shows that the term 'lexeme' was coined back in the 30s, but that's not important here.

Answer (score 2):

I think "put together" can be a phrasal verb, but not in the example you gave. An example of the phrasal form would be

> He put together the crib.

which can be shifted to

> He put the crib together.

In this case, "put together" means to assemble something.

In your example, "together in a bunch" acts as an adverbial phrase that describes how she put the flowers. It can be replaced with other phrases, such as:

> She put the all the flowers haphazardly on the table.

Comment: I agree that there are different levels of cohesiveness: 'put together N or put N together' = 'assemble N' **AND** 'put the Ns together or put together all the Ns' = 'put all the Ns into a close-knit pile/bunch/room/category ...'. I _do_ regard compounds like 'ink well' or MWVs like 'sell out' as single lexemes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that "inkwell" is a compound noun, also "ashtray" etc. "Sell-out" is a compound noun in, for e.g. "The concert was a sell-out". But in, for e.g., "The concert was "sold out", "sold out" is not a 'multi-word verb'; rather, sold" is a prepositional verb with the PP "out" as complement. In that example, "sold out" is a constituent, but it's not a constituent at word level; it's just "sold" that is a verb.

Comment: Try **phrasal lexeme**. Sold and sold out do not have the same meaning.

Comment: @BillJ But inkwell, ink-well and ink well [not the verb + adverb incarnation] are interchangeable. Spelling variants.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think so. Dictionaries rightly give it as a compound noun, a single word, not a word sequence: [link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inkwell?q=inkwell) / [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inkwell) / [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inkwell)

Comment: @BillJ Dictionaries give the spelling variants hot pot and hotpot for the lexeme: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hotpot) / [Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hot+pot) ///   {[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hot%20pot) and [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hot-pot) have the open form only; [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hotpot) only the closed form}. //// [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/particle-board#google_vignette) has 'particle board or particleboard'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree with those who give it as a word sequence, "Hotpot" passes the tests foe compoundhood.  As you know, I don't subscribe to the idea of there being such a thing as an 'open compound'. To me, it's a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't remember if you have a copy of CGEL. If you have, there's an excellent section on compounds in Ch19.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *She put all the flowers together in one big bunch.*

I very much dislike the term 'phrasal verb' since it implies that the verb and its complement form a single lexeme at word level, which is not the case.

Much better is the term 'prepositional verb', in that the verb selects a particular preposition for a certain meaning.

In your example, "put" selects the preposition "together" for the sense of "assemble", or "combine".

Note also that "together" is a 'particle' in that it can occur after the direct object, as in [1], or between the verb and its direct object, as in [2].

> [2] *She put together all the flowers in one big bunch.*

Comment: Some theories call them phrasal lexemes, and there is even research on how they are perceived in the brain.